# Element Plus: How to style the rendered components

Tags: vuejs3, element-plus

I am trying to style element plus' [`el-radio-button`](http://element-plus.org/en-US/component/radio.html#button-style) in a `el-radio-group` to have different colours. It is not available by the `el-radio-button` properties, so I'm trying to target the rendered html elements. When I inspect my webpage, something like the following is shown:

```html
<label class="el-radio-button" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1" data-v-bf51d4b2="" style="color: red;">
  <input class="el-radio-button__original-radio" type="radio" name="" tabindex="-1" value="Karthus">
  <span class="el-radio-button__inner">Karthus</span>
</label>
```

The styles are applied on `label.el-radio-button` and `span.el-radio-button__inner` but I can't seem to target them using the following styles in my sfc:

```html
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.el-radio-button {
  color: red;
  padding: 20em;

  .el-radio-button__inner {
    color: blue;

    &:hover {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

None of these are applying. I can't really tell whether it's because of specificity, or just overrides, etc. `!important` on the color properties also don't seem to apply. Is there a way to properly target the rendered html elements in the sfc style?

Comment: did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use more specific css selectors and it should work

```
<style>
  .el-radio-group .el-radio-button {
    color: red;
    padding: 20em;
  }
  
  .el-radio-group .el-radio-button__inner {
    color: blue;
  }
  
  .el-radio-group .el-radio-button__inner:hover {
      color: red;
  }  
</style>
```

[example](https://element-plus.run/#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)

Comment: I ended up creating my own component, but I have looked a bit further into this. You are right that there needs to be more specificity, but also it seems that having styles `scoped` or not also affects whether the styles are applied to the rendered components, which seems obvious on hindsight. Just the original code and removing `scoped` from `<style>` seems to apply some, not all, of the custom css.